# Can I think of convergence as an independent mathematical object?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Recently I studied convergence of sequence of real numbers in an introductory analysis course.

1. Can I think of convergence as an independent mathematical object just as we think of numbers and functions as mathematical objects?
2. If I can think of convergence as an independent object does there exist a larger class of objects to which convergence belongs, just like polynomials belong to the larger class of algebraic expressions?

Comment: It's hard. Functions and numbers can be boiled down to a particular set, thus allowing us to think of them as objects. Convergence, on the other hand, is a property of objects. However, you might be able to talk about the collection of convergent sequences/functions/what have you.

Comment: In a certain sense, point-set topology can be considered the study of convergence, in the sense that everything that can be said in point-set topology can be recast into the language of convergence. However it cannot all be recast into the language of convergence of *sequences*; this level of generality requires you to consider convergence of so-called *nets*.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to (1) is probably hard to come by, as @AndrewWray comments. Convergence is a property of some objects (for example, sequences of numbers).

The answer to (2) is "yes" in an appropriate sense. *Topology* is the branch of mathematics that deals with things like convergence in a more abstract way. A *topological space* is an object in which you can think about the convergence of a sequence. So topological spaces may be the larger class of objects that you are trying to imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Convergence is more like a *concept* rather than an *object*.

One can think about convergence of *other objects*. One cannot manipulate convergence as one usually does with mathematical objects.